# How to stretch container width based on label text length?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a custom button with label and icon.
The problem is, if the label text is too long, it will overflow.
My goal is to make the button responsive, based on the label text width, using CSS.

This is what I managed to get so far:  [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tymudy/5kwme2Ls/)

```css
.btn_container{
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
}

.btn_label{
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

.btn_icon{
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

label{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn_container">
  <div class="btn_label">
    <label>Text i want to fit in the div...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_icon">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, if the label text overflows, "btn_label" and "btn_container" width should be stretched according to the label text width.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Hello. Please also share the CSS code

Comment: Hey Timea ! Can you provide a jsfiddle with your try ? Check about the property word-wrap: normal. It could be the hack.

Comment: @Remy do not ask for jsfiddle. SO has it's own snippet here and that's what the OP should use

Comment: I don't want to get too off-topic, but I don't believe you are supposed to use the label tag inside the button tag. Also, we'd need to see your btn_ css classes to determine why the button is not automatically growing.

Comment: Hi, thx for your response... I made a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tymudy/5kwme2Ls/ illustrating what's the main problem...  So I have a long text for the label and I wan't to stretch the parent div so the text could fit in the same line.

Comment: if you want to stretch the parent div ( `.btn_container` ) , why you set `width:100px` to it? :)

Comment: I set the (.btn_container) width just to show you what the problem is. The width should be set based on the label text length. If I leave it without setting the width, it will inherit the width of the "window bottom"(in case of jsfiddle) and that is not my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code shared by you in the fiddle

1. If you want to stretch the parent div ( .btn_container ) , why you set width:100px to it? use `width:auto`
2. Do not use `float:left` this causes elements to go out of the default flow of the document and so you need to set a width to `btn_container`, which you don't want
3. If you use `position:absolute` on the text, it's width will be never taken into consideration by other elements. So avoid using position:absolute if you want it's parent to have width depending on it's width

see snippet with a solution below or  [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/2125/)

```css
.btn_container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn_label {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block
}

.btn_icon {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn_container">
  <div class="btn_label">
    <label>Text i want to fit in the div...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn_icon">
    <i class="fa fa-plus">+</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: @TimeaSorban glad i could help :D . do not forget to rate my answer as accepted. thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should make a breakup points with @media (min-width or max-width).
On smaller resolutions make the second button bellow and use less text.

Or make text overflow: hidden; and white-space: nowrap;

You can't make 40px height and put a lot of text, on desktop its ok but on a phone that text must go somewhere or make it hidden with overflow.